# transform xarray to 3D and export as tif file with rioxarray

Tags: multidimensional-array, python-xarray, dimensions

I have a multidimensional xarray. I want to select a specific value for the dimension called `number` and then get rid of it and only keep `step`, `latitude` and `longitude` dimensions and export the xarray as a tif file for a variable.

This is my starting xarray:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:            (number: 2, step: 2, latitude: 45, longitude: 45)
Coordinates:
  * number             (number) int32 1 2
    time               datetime64[ns] ...
  * step               (step) timedelta64[ns] 06:00:00 12:00:00
    heightAboveGround  float64 ...
  * latitude           (latitude) float64 28.8 28.4 28.0 27.6 ... 12.0 11.6 11.2
  * longitude          (longitude) float64 111.6 112.0 112.4 ... 128.8 129.2
    valid_time         (step) datetime64[ns] dask.array<chunksize=(2,), meta=np.ndarray>
Data variables:
    v10                (number, step, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(2, 2, 15, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
    u10                (number, step, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(2, 2, 15, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            2
    GRIB_centre:             ecmf
    GRIB_centreDescription:  European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    GRIB_subCentre:          0
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    history:                 2023-07-11T10:38 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0.9.1...
```

Here I have masked the xarray so that only one `number` is returned and I have tried to squeeze the dimension but it's still there.

```
ensemble = 1
mask = (xarr.number.values == ensemble)
xarr1 = xarr.sel(number=mask).squeeze(drop=True)
xarr1.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True) # set wgs84 proj to xarray
```

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:            (number: 0, step: 2, latitude: 45, longitude: 45)
Coordinates:
  * number             (number) int32 
    time               datetime64[ns] ...
  * step               (step) timedelta64[ns] 06:00:00 12:00:00
    heightAboveGround  float64 ...
  * latitude           (latitude) float64 28.8 28.4 28.0 27.6 ... 12.0 11.6 11.2
  * longitude          (longitude) float64 111.6 112.0 112.4 ... 128.8 129.2
    valid_time         (step) datetime64[ns] dask.array<chunksize=(2,), meta=np.ndarray>
    spatial_ref        int32 0
Data variables:
    v10                (number, step, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(0, 2, 15, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
    u10                (number, step, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(0, 2, 15, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            2
    GRIB_centre:             ecmf
    GRIB_centreDescription:  European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    GRIB_subCentre:          0
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    history:                 2023-07-11T10:56 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0.9.1...
```

I calculate the wind speed and add it as a new variable called `ws` to the xarray

```
ds2 = xarr1.assign(ws=(xarr1["u10"] ** 2 + xarr1["v10"] ** 2) ** 0.5)
```

I create a new xarray containing only the wind speed variable

```
xarr_ws = ds2.ws
```

```
<xarray.DataArray 'ws' (number: 0, step: 2, latitude: 45, longitude: 45)>
dask.array<pow, shape=(0, 2, 45, 45), dtype=float32, chunksize=(0, 2, 24, 24), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * number             (number) int32 
    time               datetime64[ns] ...
  * step               (step) timedelta64[ns] 06:00:00 12:00:00
    heightAboveGround  float64 ...
  * latitude           (latitude) float64 28.8 28.4 28.0 27.6 ... 12.0 11.6 11.2
  * longitude          (longitude) float64 111.6 112.0 112.4 ... 128.8 129.2
    valid_time         (step) datetime64[ns] dask.array<chunksize=(2,), meta=np.ndarray>
    spatial_ref        int32 0
```

Use rioxarray to export to a tif file but this fails because I have 4 dimensions rather than 3.

```
# save tif with wind speed with all timesteps
xarr_ws.rio.to_raster(f'{storm_name[1:]}_ens{ensemble}_wind_speed_by_timestep.tif')
```

error message:

```
in _check_dimensions raise TooManyDimensions(rioxarray.exceptions.TooManyDimensions: Only 2D and 3D data arrays supported. Data variable: ws
```

How do I reduce the dimensions from `(number: 0, step: 2, latitude: 45, longitude: 45)` to `(step: 2, latitude: 45, longitude: 45)` ?

I have tried `.squeeze('number')`, `.drop(dim='number')` and `.drop_dims(number)` with no luck

Comment: After the masking operation, 0 slices of the dimension number were taken, I believe it is not the way you want your dataset to be.

Comment: Thank you @cyril well spotted. My code is actually correct, the problem was that the value I used for ```ensemble``` was not part of the ```number``` dimension.